Python script runs alone (from cmd) but not when it's in subprocess: error about requests module
I have a wrapper script that is running five other scripts in a subprocess and passing a config_file for each sub-script. First and last two scripts run without issues, but the middle one is causing issues. I have a virtual environment set up with all my dependencies, including the requests module. In the middle script I use the requests module to call an API.
This middle script works totally fine when I pass the config_file to it from the command prompt, but when I run it as part of the wrapper, it gives an error and says
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Leis.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I have deactivated and removed my environment, re-set it up, confirmed I have requests in there. I can't seem to get inside the main function when running from wrapper, but it does fine on its own. Please help!
wrapper code:
for script in config["scripts"]:
        script_name = os.path.basename(script)
        logging.info(f"Running {script_name}")
        sp.run(["python", script, config_file], 
               stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, 
               text=True, check=True, bufsize=1)
    logging.info(f".....")

leis.py code:
import requests
import sys
import os
import logging
from utils import setup_logging, load_config, check_files_exist
 

def get_registration(lei):
    try:
        url = f".........."
        payload = {}
        headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'}
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        json = response.json()
        if not json:
            return [None, None]
        registered_at_id = json.....


Removed, re-created virtual env (to ensure 'requests' installation)
Ran script on its own (working)


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a minimal reproducible example.  The thing with running with subprocess,  you need to specify the exact python binary, the same one that's associated with the pip env.   Just using python, you could be using the binary that comes with the system and not the virtual env one.   That's my speculation.

First I'd check that the python interpreter you're running the wrapper script is correct - try which (or where.exe in Windows) to see. If that's right, maybe try running which from your wrapper script and see what it finds.

Also PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME environment variables might be set, if they are make sure they're set correctly. ALso they must be exported, not just set in the shell.

Why do you  want to run Python as a subprocess of itself anyway? There are legitimate uses of that but this doesn't seem to be one of them.


subprocess.run(["python", script…

Are you sure python in the PATH is the right Python? When you want to run a script under the same interpreter as the current script use sys.executable:
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.run([sys.executable, script…

On the other hand are you sure the current interpreter is the one that has access to the venv with requests?

Your example must be incomplete.
If you:

create a virtual environment
activate it
create two scripts 'main.py' and 'work.py' with the content below
execute 'main.py' from the active environment

You will find that work.py (which imports and uses requests) works without issues.
Content for main.py:
from subprocess import run, PIPE

p = run(["python", "work.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True, check=True, bufsize=1)
print(p.stdout)

And work.py:
import requests

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
print(response.status_code)

Running python main.py from the environment, the output is:
200

Note that the run command uses the same arguments as your call. The configuration file has been left off but that's just unrelated stuff anyway - unless you mess around with your environment from code you didn't share based on configuration you didn't share.
Given that this works without issues  - as it should, since subprocess.run() inherits the same environment - we can only conclude you're not sharing enough of your code to reproduce the issue. I would suggest taking my minimal example here,  and add elements from your code to reproduce the issue, and share the resulting minimal example in your question to allow others to help resolve your actual issue.
Note: it seems mostly likely that in your setup, python does not match the same Python you are using to start the main script - or that it does, but that this is not the python.exe in the environment you have created, that has requests in it. If that's the case, running my example script here should give you the same result - and the issue is with the configuration of your editor / IDE / the way you run your script.
